# How to use html template in springboot using JWT Authentication?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, thymeleaf

For a few days I have begun to learn to work with springboot and particularly with spring security for user authentication, for this I have decided to make an apirest using a system in which the user authenticates and can access the service according to their specific role.

I used this post as a guide: https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/spring-security-jwt-authentication-postgresql-restapis-springboot-spring-mvc-spring-jpa

in which it is used
Spring Security JWT Authentication PostgreSQL - RestAPIs SpringBoot Spring MVC Spring JPA

I would like to integrate it with html templates, perhaps using thymeleaf dependency in pom.xml, bootstrap and jquery (not with Agular React or Vuejs since this is the way I should do it in my work due to a compatibility problem)

I have also seen several tutorials where thymeleaf is used but does not include JWT Authentication

Could someone tell me how to complete this exercise? Any tutorial explaining how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the anotations like `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")` from your link should work the same for thymeleaf endpoints.

eg.:

```
@Controller
public class ThymeleafController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public String hello() {
        return "thymeleaf-template";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but i need to start with home page first, for example home.html `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Security with Spring Boot</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, This is Home page!</h1>
<a style="color: blue" th:href="@{/user}">User Page</a>
<br />
<a style="color: blue" th:href="@{/admin}">Admin Page</a>
</body>
</html>` and then redirect to thymeleaf-template, the problem is: what can i do this?

Comment: if you want so serve additional static files from your Spring Boot app, you could save this files in src/main/resources/static. These files will be available during runtime. eg. a file src/main/resources/static/home.html is accessible at localhost:8080/home.html

Comment: yes, but, how to capture the token from the html template?

Comment: if you want some logic to happen you have to write a Spring Boot Controller.
To read a token from the HTTP request your Method should have an annotated parameter. see example here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers#accessing
For Json Web Tokens your Request header is named authorization instead of "accept-language" and your injected parameter value is a String starting with "Bearer ..." which you can parse with your desired library.

Comment: Spring security and JWT authorizes your request. You just need to validate URL using token. I am giving you a github link you may try that code. https://github.com/PallavRaj14/purchase-history/tree/jwt-authentication
After authorization you may return whatever you want to return.